# Elmongo plugin for full text search

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to use the Elmongo plugin for Node.js and I'm having some trouble with the plugin. Here is my code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var elmongo = require('elmongo');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var twitterSchema = new Schema ({
 id: {type: Number, index: {unique: true, dropDups: true}},
 created_at: Date,
 user: [{
 id: Number,
 name: String,
 screen_name: String,
 location: String
 }],
 text: String,
 keywords: []
});

twitterSchema.plugin(elmongo);

var Tweets = mongoose.model('Tweets', twitterSchema);

twitterSchema.sync(function(err, numSynced){
 console.log("number of tweets synced: " + numSynced);
});

twitterSchema.search({query: 'flu'}, function(err, results){

 console.log('search results: ' + results);

});

exports.Document = function(db) {

 return db.model('Tweets');

};
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'elmongo'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Documents/UCIMedCenterProject/MedStream-feature.sentiment-analysis/models.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I looked up some of the errors and what I get is that I need to reinstall the module, but that didn't work either. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should install this module in your project directory (go to your project directory in command line and then run "npm install elmongo")

Answer (score 0):

You should check inside node_modules folder if any folder with name elmongo is present. If not try installing the module again.
Try installing as administrator.

> sudo npm install elmongo